# In node, How to get notified whenever current execution context completes?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, event-loop

I want to track end of the current execution context. is there any event that will be emitted whenever current execution context completed?

```
console.log('starts');
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('set timeout called');
}, 100);


// something similar like this 
process.on('async', function(){
console.log('current execution context finished. event loop going to 
execute the next one!'); 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by current execution context ?

Comment: current execution context is what are all things that executed before eventloop.